# Which is correct, "shot with an iPhone" or "shot on an iPhone"?

Tags: prepositions

I have used one of these variations (with/on) in a published video. Now one of the industry critics is saying that it should have been the other. So would highly appreciate if the correct preposition is established for the benefit of the entire English-speaking human race for centuries to come. Thank you! :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't think I'd bat an eye at either wording. Both are grammatically correct, and both are semantically meaningful.

Comment: Which one does the critic prefer? I suppose "shot with an iPhone" is technically correct, since you aren't using film. But, that is a very "pedagogical" answer.

Comment: If you are an gadget fan, it's *with*, if you are a camera buff, it's *on*, and if you are a serious photography techno then neither but *using*. All are correct in their own fields. Take a pic using your iPhone & send, it may reach with a foot note 'Shot xxx my iPhone.' and you will know what Apple thinks it should be.

Comment: My immediate reaction upon reading the title of the question (out of context, and naturally a reaction that lasted only half a second) was, “Oh! Have they actually made a firearms app now. So much for gun control…”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet if someone stands on your iPhone, and in a rage at this you shoot them, then clearly they were shot *on* an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

> Shot with an iPhone.

This is clearly a correct use. The picture was *shot*. The *iPhone* was used to do this. There is a sense of *with* that relates this use of action to tool.

> Shot on an iPhone.

This is interestingly correct, in two different ways.

The pictures was *shot*. Historically, *on* was used to relate the act of taking pictures to the type of film stock used, but has a very long use referring to the type of equipment used more generally. While one might object that the relationship between act and medium originally suggested by *on* relates more to the film than the device, the use for referring to the camera too is well-established. And were it not well-established, we would have to coin it any way, to refer to the virtual medium that is used instead of film stock.

*On* is also used to refer to the relationship between a computer program and the computer that executes it. When you use an *iPhone* or any other such phone* to take a photograph, you use one or more camera applications *on* that device. (*On* referring both to the relationship of the software to the device, and to the relationship of the act of using the software to the device).

It's amusing that the correctness of this stands up in the face of different attitudes to the device: If we consider it as comparable to all other cameras, then we would use *on* because we would with any other camera. If however we dismiss it as a camera, then we should forget about what terms are used with cameras and consider it as a small electronic computer, and use *on*.

Both are hence defensible.

In terms of attestation, both can be found frequently used, whether of phones, other digital cameras, or of film-based photography too.

Now. If you were writing in detail about the photographic process, there might be an advantage in distinguishing between the medium (whether digital or different types of film stock) and the device, and so say e.g. "shot on high-speed black and white film with a Nikon F3". In the context of such use we might favour *with* over *on*, though the distinction between medium and device is weaker with digital. In general, the nits just aren't there to pick.

*This itself showing the way words from earlier technological stages carry through to later developments; it's increasingly rare to carry a phone these days, as more and more of us carry small pocket-sized computers which have mobile telephony as just one of their many potential uses, but we tend to still call them "phones".

Comment: Thorough and informative. +1.